# Importing .CSV file to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have .csv file which I want to import to my database using the SQL syntax. This is how my .csv file looks like:

```
"john"
"james"
"peter"
"andrew"
"harry"
"king"
"hanny"
"charles"
```

So I ran this code in my SQL syntax:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (names)
```

But this is what I get when inserted:

```
john"
"james"
"peter"
"andrew"
"harry"
"king"
"hanny"
"charles
```

Please how do I make each name to be inserted in each row

Comment: It looks to me as if your lines are not terminated by `\n`. You should check that. Maybe try `\r` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on Windows, the rows in your CSV are delimited by a carriage return \r and an escape sequence \n. Therefore you have to use

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

instead:

[image: Import values from CSV]